# Get indices of nonzero values in numpy array with allowance for repeated indices with value > 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given

```
>>> a = np.array((0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1))
```

one can find the index location of non-zero values using:

```
>>> np.nonzero(a)  # or ~equivalently np.argwhere(a)
(array([1, 5, 7]),)
```

However, what I really want is `(array([1, 5, 5, 7]),)`, because the value in `a[5]` is `2` - i.e. the value of `a` at an index is how many times that index should appear in the output.

My current thinking, since the maximum value will not be very large, is to do:

```
# pseudo
indices = np.nonzero(a)
while extra_indices:
    a -= 1
    extra_indices = np.nonzero(a)
    indices = np.concat(indices, extra_indices)
```

Is there a better way? (Although the maximum number won't be large, the arrays can be quite big so I'd prefer to remove the iterating step)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `repeat`:

```
idx = np.nonzero(a)

out = np.repeat(idx,a[idx])
# array([1, 5, 5, 7])
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple I'd overlooked.. thanks.